# accessory checkmark, one at a time in a uitableview-iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI,
how to implement checkmark, one at a time in a uitableview.and then how to save that state in my application? please guide.
right now i am having a table and the data in table row is coming from a nsmutablearray.My .m file is as:

```
#import "LocationSelection.h"

@implementation LocationSelection  
@synthesize menuList, table;  

- (void)viewDidLoad {  
    menuList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"LOCATION1",nil],  
              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"LOCATION2",nil],   
              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"LOCATION3",nil],  
              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"LOCATION4",nil],  
              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"LOCATION5",nil],  
              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"LOCATION6",nil],  
              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"LOCATION7",nil],  
              nil];  

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];      
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];     
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;        
    self.title=@"Location Selection";           
    [table reloadData];    
    [super viewDidLoad];    
}  
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView{  
    return 1;  
}  

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  
    return 40;  
}  

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return menuList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];  
    }
    cell.highlighted=NO;  
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;  

    NSArray *rowArray = [menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    UILabel *nameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 8, 200, 20)]autorelease];    
    nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[rowArray objectAtIndex:0]];  
    nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
    nameLabel.shadowColor=[UIColor whiteColor];  
    nameLabel.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.5);  
    nameLabel.textColor = RGB(0,0,0);
    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]];  
    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];    
    return cell;  

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment this line in cellForRowAtIndexPath -> `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;`
Use this:

```
NSIndexPath* lastIndexPath; // This as an ivar

  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell* newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
        int newRow = [indexPath row]; 
        int oldRow = (lastIndexPath != nil) ? [lastIndexPath row] : -1; 

        if(newRow != oldRow) 
        { 
            newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            UITableViewCell* oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath]; 
            oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            lastIndexPath = indexPath; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: May be your haven't read question , check the function name where you are setting accessoryType type,

Comment: Thanks for rep & code but as i am clicking on any of the row application getting crashed.And problem is in UITableViewCell* oldCell.....I have check it on debugger saying the variable oldCell out of scope.Please help in fixing it, till I am trying to fix it.

Comment: @Maddy make NSIndexPath* lastIndexPath; that an ivar instead of local variable.

Comment: hey macdev thank you very much!i have implemented it properly and now i am reading tutorial on persisting the ticked row value!be ready i may ask question :) to u.

Answer (score 1):

In your MenuList you should stock NSDictionaries having 2 keys:

- location
- visited (if the location should have the checkmark)

NSDictionary *loc = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys
@"Location 1", @"location",
@"NO", @"visited", nil, nil];

When setting up the cell you would test to see if the "visited" key has a value:

```
if ([[menuList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"visited"]){
// the location was visited
// setup the checkmark
}
```

Lastly, to fill in the name of the location, instead of:

```
nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[rowArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

put

```
nameLabel.text = [[rowArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"location"];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: And then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you'll get the row that was selected, set ALL the "checked" fields to NO, set the state of the "checked" field for the chosen row to YES, and call `[tableView reloadData]` to refresh the display. (And run the row deselection animation, a-course.) This is the "one at a time" part.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Instead of

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

in your code ...

Comment: That applies to all the cells drawn. His question was One at a time.

Comment: &@macdev thank you both for the reply actually it was my fault to uncomment the "UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator".But application being crashed saying("Debugger says"), oldCell out of scope.Help in fixing this issue